# extracting "author" from a book in amazon with Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup, extract

I am trying this for days now and it won't wort.
i want the name of the author of this book 
"http://www.amazon.de/Weit-weg-ganz-Jojo-Moyes-ebook/dp/B00H07CB9O/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=undefined&sr=1-1".

As firebug shows it is located in the following code.

```
<html>
...
<div class="buying">
    <h1 class="parseasinTitle">
    <span>
       <span class="contributorNameTrigger" asin="B001HMNFPMB00H07CB9O">
       <a id="contributorNameTriggerB001HMNFPMB00H07CB9O" href="http://www.amazon.de/Jojo-Moyes/e   /B001HMNFPM/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1" asin="B001HMNFPMB00H07CB9O">Jojo Moyes</a>
    <a href="#" asin="B001HMNFPMB00H07CB9O">
    </span>
...
</html>
```

i tryed to select the name with

```
doc.getElementsByClass("contributorNameTrigger")
```

but it doesn't work.then i used the class "buying" and tried to select the span and the span class but it doesn't work neither

```
doc.getElementsByClass("buying").select("span").select("span[class=contributorNameTrigger");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does that library of yours really have a `getElementByClass` method (in singular)?

Comment: sorry my mistake. it is getElementsByClass()!

Comment: but still no output:(

Comment: But if you were calling the wrong method, code should not even compile :-?

Comment: it compiles.i didn't paste the one line from eclipse and just wrote it by hand-thats why:)

Comment: Well, yeah, you suggested that fixing the typo didn't fix the issue, thus my comment.

Answer (score 0):

it finally works with the following code:

```
Element author = doc.getElementsByClass("buying").select("span").select("a").first();
```

Thanx for the answers!